# Look for matches in PHP array then combine the array without any overwriting

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array and I can't seem to figure out how to look at each array item and check if a `[Product Name]` matches another array item's `[Product Name]` or not?

*Below is sample data.* **For example**, `array[0]` and `array[1]` both have the same `[Product Name]` of `test` but different values for things like `[Variant Name]` or `[Variant Full Stock]`. I want to be able to find matches like that and combine those somehow to one array but **not** overwrite anything.

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
            [Product Name] => test
            [Variant Name] => Default
            [Variant SKU] => 
            [Variant In Stock] => 1
            [Variant Full Stock] => 1
            [id] => 0
        )
    [1] => Array (
            [Product Name] => test
            [Variant Name] => testingVar
            [Variant SKU] => 
            [Variant In Stock] => 1
            [Variant Full Stock] => 2
            [id] => 1
        )
    [2] => Array (
            [Product Name] => another test
            [Variant Name] => Default
            [Variant SKU] => 
            [Variant In Stock] => 1
            [Variant Full Stock] => 1
            [id] => 2
        )
)
```

Ideally, I would want to convert the above array to a new array that would output something like this:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [0] => Array (
            [Product Name] => test
            [Variant Name] => Default
            [Variant SKU] => 
            [Variant In Stock] => 1
            [Variant Full Stock] => 1
            [id] => 0
        )
        [1] => Array (
            [Product Name] => test
            [Variant Name] => testingVar
            [Variant SKU] => 
            [Variant In Stock] => 1
            [Variant Full Stock] => 2
            [id] => 1
        )
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [Product Name] => another test
        [Variant Name] => Default
        [Variant SKU] => 
        [Variant In Stock] => 1
        [Variant Full Stock] => 1
        [id] => 2
    )
)
```

**Any solutions?**

Comment: you do realize, that the second example you provided is not in a valid form, however you could create a new array
array(array(array(default), array(testvar)),array(array(another test)))

Comment: you should put the Product Name as the key of your array and use array_key_exists

Comment: I'm doing it, wait a little bit.

Comment: @19greg96 What would be the valid form but somehow combining those? As you can tell, I'm a bit lost... haha I just would need it to combine somehow so I could use foreach and each item in the foreach would be unique in the way I mentioned above, if that makes sense...

Comment: @PLB I've tried various solutions that I found throughout stackoverflow, various versions of functions with array_merge/array_combine but can't seem to get any of those to work.

Comment: @19greg96 I think I fixed it so it would be in valid form...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is iterate the array and group by `Product Name`

```
$data =
    array(
        array(
            "Product Name" => "test",
            "Variant Name" => "Default",
            "Variant SKU" => "",
            "Variant In Stock" => 1,
            "Variant Full Stock" => 1,
            "id" => 0
        ),
        array(
            "Product Name" => "test",
            "Variant Name" => "testingVar",
            "Variant SKU" => "",
            "Variant In Stock" => 1,
            "Variant Full Stock" => 2,
            "id" => 1
        ),
        array(
            "Product Name" => "another test",
            "Variant Name" => "testingVar",
            "Variant SKU" => "",
            "Variant In Stock" => 1,
            "Variant Full Stock" => 2,
            "id" => 2
        ),
    );

$result = array();

foreach($data as $item) {
    $key = $item["Product Name"];
    $result[$key][] = $item;
}
```

`$result` looks like this:

```
array(2) {
  ["test"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(6) {
      ["Product Name"]=>
      string(4) "test"
      ["Variant Name"]=>
      string(7) "Default"
      ["Variant SKU"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["Variant In Stock"]=>
      int(1)
      ["Variant Full Stock"]=>
      int(1)
      ["id"]=>
      int(0)
    }
    [1]=>
    array(6) {
      ["Product Name"]=>
      string(4) "test"
      ["Variant Name"]=>
      string(10) "testingVar"
      ["Variant SKU"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["Variant In Stock"]=>
      int(1)
      ["Variant Full Stock"]=>
      int(2)
      ["id"]=>
      int(1)
    }
  }
  ["another test"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(6) {
      ["Product Name"]=>
      string(12) "another test"
      ["Variant Name"]=>
      string(10) "testingVar"
      ["Variant SKU"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["Variant In Stock"]=>
      int(1)
      ["Variant Full Stock"]=>
      int(2)
      ["id"]=>
      int(2)
    }
  }
}
```

Not exactly what you had in mind, but perhaps a bit more usable?

Comment: That works perfectly! That combined them the way I wanted! I may not explained what I wanted correctly, but that gave me what I wanted! Haha Thanks!

Comment: @ZachReed Heh, that's what being a software engineer means, giving customers what they actually want, not what they asked for ;)

Answer (score 2):

Althought you already have your answer, I started to code something, so I wanted to finish it.

```
$newar=array();
$k=0;
while($ar[0])
{
    $keys=array();
    foreach($ar as $k2=>$v2)if($ar[0]['Product Name']==$ar[$k2]['Product Name']&&$k2!=0)$keys[]=$k2;
    $newar[$k]=array($ar[0]);
    unset($ar[0]);
    foreach($keys as $x)
    {
        $newar[$k][]=$ar[$x];
        unset($ar[$x]);
    }
    ++$k;
    $ar=array_values($ar);
}
$ar=$newar;
```

For example, this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Product Name] => test
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Product Name] => test
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Product Name] => another test
        )

)
```

will become:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Product Name] => test
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [Product Name] => test
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Product Name] => another test
                )

        )

)
```